# c# how to get name based on enum

Tags: c#, enums

Here I have small table Like Employee

```
EmpId   EmpName   EmpType
1       John       1
2       Mick       3
3       Smith      2
```

I wrote a simple Linq query finding details Like

```
public Users GetUsers(int Id)
        { var x = from n in db.Users
                    where n.Username == Id
                    select n;
            return x.FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

when its get result  as EmpId=1,EmpName=John,Emptype=1 Insted of 1 i need Admin from enum

```
 enum TypeofEmp{
            Admin=1,
            HttpRequest=2,
            Devoloper=3
    };
```

How can i get these values

Comment: What is the type of `Emptype` property in the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enum.GetName` method:

```
Enum.GetName( typeof( TypeofEmp ), value );
```

Also, if you want to convert an `int` value to instance of your enum, you can do simple cast, for example:

```
var enumInstance = ( TypeofEmp )1;
```

Comment: how can i write in Linq query

Comment: @Md That has nothing to do with the query, but with how you're formatting the resulting string.

Comment: i'm Getting Result as  EmpId=1,EmpName=John,Emptype=1   but how can i convert Emptype=1 as Emptype=Admin   var enumInstance = ( TypeofEmp )1;  where i use this

Answer (score 1):

[Enum.GetValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an array of all values;

```
foreach(var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeofEmp)))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{(TypeofEmp)value} (integer value: {(int)value})");
}

// output:
Admin (integer value: 1)
HttpRequest (integer value: 2)
Devoloper (integer value: 3)
```

Comment: @fredrink how can i write in Linq query